# Javascript Accessing dom element directly and using a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, dom

Why is doing

```
var consoleElem = document.getElementById("debug");
consoleElem.appendChild(msgElement)
```

the same thing as

```
document.getElementById('debug').appendChild(msgElement);
```

It seems to me that the DOM element (debug) is its own variable, and then to copy it to another variable means I have two copies of the debug element... why should any changes I make to the new copy (var consoleElem) make changes to the original DOM element?

Comment: It doesn't copy it.  It only creates a reference to the element.  To copy you have to call cloneNode() I believe.

Answer (score 1):

What is in the consoleElem isn't the DOM element itself but instead a reference to it.. so any change that's done through the reference is actually applied to the DOM element itself..

If you want to modify an element without actually changing the original element itself then you should clone it.. jQuery offers a clone functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The call `document.getElementById` returns a reference to a DOM element. All that the line

```
var consoleElem = document.getElementById("debug");
```

does is store that reference in a variable; it doesn't create anything. You can have a dozen variables referring to the same element, and it's still just one element.

If you want to create an element, use `document.createElement`. If you want to copy an element, use `newElement = oldElement.cloneNode()`.